# OneHotEncoder ,TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drop'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn 0.20.3 documentation, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html **init** has parameter drop, but when I use the same it's throwing a type error.

I didn't find any examples using the "drop" Keyword, most of the examples I have seen are using the older version of sklearn. And in some cases, they used ColumnTransfer (even that's for the older version of OnehotEncoder as it gives Future Warning)

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = [0],handle_unknown='ignore',drop=[0])
```

Expected results: should be able to compile the above code.
Actual results: TypeError (**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drop')

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = [0],handle_unknown='ignore',drop[0])
```

Possible explanation from docs:
None : retain all features (the default).
‘first’ : drop the first category in each feature. If only one category is present, the feature will be dropped entirely.
**array : drop[i] is the category in feature X[:, i] that should be dropped.**

---

Try this:
I have a function that can do the job for you:

```
# Own implementation of One Hot Encoding - Data Transformation
def convert_to_binary(df, column_to_convert):
    categories = list(df[column_to_convert].drop_duplicates())

    for category in categories:
        cat_name = str(category).replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "_").replace("-", "").lower()
        col_name = column_to_convert[:5] + '_' + cat_name[:10]
        df[col_name] = 0
        df.loc[(df[column_to_convert] == category), col_name] = 1

    return df

# One Hot Encoding
print("One Hot Encoding categorical data...")
columns_to_convert = [col1,col2]#Enter your column names here that you want to one hot encode.

for column in df_all.columns:              #columns_to_convert
    if df_all.column.dtype == 'category':
        df_all = convert_to_binary(df=df_all, column_to_convert=column)
        df_all.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
print("One Hot Encoding categorical data...completed")
```

Make sure you enter your list of columns (if you dont want all categorical variables to be converted) in the columns_to_convert

Comment: it didnt help , gives __SyntaxError__: positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

the link you provide is not for the 0.20 version, but the latest. Check version 0.20.3: https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder
On that version, the argument is not documented. So a solution to the problem would be updating tot he latest version of SKlearn.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your current version of scikit-learn should resolve the issue:

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn
```